# What are differences between K-means versions: Lloyd, Forgy, Macquen, Hartigan and other?

Tags: clustering, algorithms, k-means

I'm looking for the (perhaps brief) explanation of the main differences between the different K-means clustering procedures, such as between Lloyd, Forgy, MacQueen and Hartigan, and possibly other versions. I'm confusing these versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [K-Means: Lloyd,Forgy,MacQueen,Hartigan-Wong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446053/k-means-lloyd-forgy-macqueen-hartigan-wong)

Comment: Which duplication? There are differences between these versions. For example there are iterative and no iterative versions. Another example, one version computes the class center when one data point is assigned to one class and another version computes the class center when all data points are assigned to classes.

Comment: Nabiltos, if one removes away the issue of how to choose initial centres, as a separate topic, and likewise removes k-means modifications such as using other distances as deviations, such as chord instead of euclidean, - then I suppose the main two classic versions of k-means algo are: (i) update centres after reassignment of all points (the usual algo), (ii) update centres after each point's reassignment (the running or online algo).